# Invalid column name 'Column' in EF Core Fluent API

Tags: entity-framework

I am trying to create a one-to-one relationship in EF Core using Fluent API but when I try to save the model it throws invalid column name exception.

```
public partial class Child
{
    public Guid? ParentId {get;set;} // this is the FK
    public virtual Parent {get;set;}
}

public partial class Parent
{
    public Guid Id {get;set;}
    public virtual Child {get;set;}
}

 entity.HasOne(d => d.Child)
         .WithOne(p => p.Parent)
         .HasForeignKey<Child>(d => d.ParentId)
         .HasConstraintName("FK_Parent_Child");
```

So when I try to save a Parent model to database I keep getting that `ParentId` is an invalid column name( it does actually exist in the database, and I also have the logger to debug SQL queries and it does point to the right table )

Comment: what is the exact error message you're getting?

Comment: An exception occurred in the database while saving changes for context type 'MyContext'.
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.
 ---> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Invalid column name 'ParentID'.